# SQL server pivot count function works incorrectly if used with inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I think there is a bug in my SQL-server pivot function because I can't find any other explanation.

I am running a simple pivot and using the exact syntax shown in MSDN.
but the pivot answer shows the exact same number for all columns with the value equivalence of the count of all weeks!!!
(left is query result and right is what I want)
[image: left is query result and right is what I want[]

here is my query:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
    r.cutomer_id
   ,c.[Week]
   ,r.id
  FROM r
  JOIN c
    ON r.Create_date = c.Date
  WHERE Is_ride = 1
  AND ((Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319)
  OR (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426))) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT(id)
FOR [Week] IN
([9], [10], [11], [12], [14], [15], [16], [17])
) AS pvt
```

here are some test data representing the "p" output (i just changed id numbers, weeks are the same number you get from the query)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
CREATE TABLE #t (
  customer_id INT
 ,WEEK INT
 ,id INT
)

INSERT #t (customer_id, WEEK, id)
  VALUES (12032, 10, 8607)
  , (43551, 10, 8721051)
  , (55025, 10, 81200)
  , (198874, 10, 861362)
  , (99675, 10, 867081)
  , (19387, 10, 863656)
  , (12526, 10, 8603706)
  , (19503, 10, 860924)
  , (37597, 10, 860909)
  , (136019, 10, 8610674);
```

so I thought there is something wrong with my query but then I changed the query to this:

```
SELECT
  r.cutomer_id
 ,c.[Week]
 ,r.id INTO #t
FROM r
JOIN c
  ON r.Create_date = c.Date
WHERE Is_ride = 1
AND ((Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319)
OR (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426))

SELECT
  *
FROM #t
PIVOT
(
COUNT(id)
FOR [Week] IN
([9], [10], [11], [12], [14], [15], [16], [17])
) AS pvt
```

and it works just fine!
also if I remove the r.id column from select and change it to `count(week)` it works fine!!!

also if I only change my `where` to

```
   WHERE Is_ride = 1
    AND ((Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319)
    OR (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426))
    and passenger_id in (43551,12032,136019)
            ) p
```

it works fine!!!

can someone give me an explanation?

Comment: *"it works fine!!! "* i very doubt it works fine because SQL tables/resultsets are by SQL definition **orderless** so using `TOP` with `ORDER BY` is pretty much **meaningless**.. In fact it can result into returning non deterministic (random) results.. To get deterministic (fixed) result always you should atleast include a column which has a primary key, unique key or you know that column has (almost) unique values like a datetime with 7 fractional seconds in a `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: because my main table is indexed and I am not doing any complex job I get the same output from top10 on each run.
I tested it before posting
ran the inner query for 100 times and the same result for all of them.

the top10 is for limiting 1milion rows to 10 simple rows.
I changed the code to select into and it works fine for all of the 1M rows

Comment: sounds like your in luck, assume it will not work annymore when you start deleting or updating things alot and table/index fragmentation becomes a thing.. Well i warned you if you want to continue playing russian roulette with your query results then it's your choice.

Comment: thanks but it was for here and sampling and give you some test case.
my main query doesn't include `top 10`.
I removed the `top 10` from the post so people don't get confused.

Comment: For anyone here to help you you need to provide an MVCE reproducing the problem or the actual execution plans (XML) . Of course `PIVOT` shouldn't return different results if you insert the exact same rows to a temp table rather than a derived table. Could be some sort of corruption in your DB, a bug, or something missing in your description

Comment: thanks, Martin.
we have very sensitive data and secure server and it's very hard to create an MVCE.
these are the exact same query's that I use and I am getting totally different results!

if there is no explanation I guess there is something wrong with my DB!

Comment: I would check/rebuild indexes or try playing around with the query to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior. Can you post your version (complete result from `SELECT @@VERSION`)?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)  
me too, same query different result on my local SQL server

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you're getting the result shown on your images. There's possibly some information missing.
Here's an MVCE with code commented to create a larger set of test data.

```
CREATE TABLE r(
    id int identity,
    customer_id int, 
    create_date date, 
    Create_date_int AS CONVERT( int, CONVERT( char(8), create_date, 112)),
    is_ride bit)
INSERT INTO r(customer_id, create_date, is_ride)
SELECT customer_id, '20190307', 1
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))x(customer_id)
--SELECT TOP 100000
--       ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10,
--       DATEADD( dd, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 120, '2019'),
--       1
--FROM sys.all_columns a, sys.all_columns b;

CREATE TABLE c(
    [Date]  date,
    [Week]  AS DATEPART( wk, [Date])
)
INSERT INTO c([Date])
SELECT  DATEADD( dd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1, '2019')
FROM sys.all_columns;
```

From here, I could run your original query that gives the expected results, just 1's in week 10.

I can also run an alternative query using cross tabs that is my preferred method to pivot data.

```
SELECT
    r.customer_id
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] =  9 THEN r.id END) AS wk9
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 10 THEN r.id END) AS wk10
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 11 THEN r.id END) AS wk11
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 12 THEN r.id END) AS wk12
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 14 THEN r.id END) AS wk14
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 15 THEN r.id END) AS wk15
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 16 THEN r.id END) AS wk16
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN c.[Week] = 17 THEN r.id END) AS wk17
FROM r
JOIN c ON r.Create_date = c.Date
WHERE Is_ride = 1
AND (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319
OR Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426) 
GROUP BY r.customer_id
ORDER BY r.customer_id;
```

That also gives the correct information.

Both of these methods might benefit from *preaggregation* to improve their performance.

```
WITH ctePreAggregate AS(
    SELECT
      r.customer_id
     ,c.[Week]
     ,COUNT(*) AS weeklycount
    FROM r
    JOIN c
      ON r.Create_date = c.Date
    WHERE Is_ride = 1
    AND (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319
    OR Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426)
    GROUP BY r.customer_id
            ,c.[Week]
)
SELECT
  *
FROM ctePreAggregate
PIVOT
(
SUM(weeklycount)
FOR [Week] IN
([9], [10], [11], [12], [14], [15], [16], [17])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY customer_id;


WITH ctePreAggregate AS(
    SELECT
      r.customer_id
     ,c.[Week]
     ,COUNT(*) AS weeklycount
    FROM r
    JOIN c
      ON r.Create_date = c.Date
    WHERE Is_ride = 1
    AND (Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190302 AND 20190319
    OR Create_date_int BETWEEN 20190406 AND 20190426)
    GROUP BY r.customer_id
            ,c.[Week]
)
SELECT
    customer_id
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] =  9 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk9
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 10 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk10
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 11 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk11
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 12 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk12
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 14 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk14
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 15 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk15
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 16 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk16
    ,SUM( CASE WHEN [Week] = 17 THEN weeklycount ELSE 0 END) AS wk17
FROM ctePreAggregate
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

The only issue is that you would need to add a series of ISNULL() in the column list to show NULLs instead of zeros for the PIVOT query.